# How to download tensorflow flower data and inception v3 model?

Tags: windows

I want to use Inception-v3 model to do transfer learning on tensorflow's flower dataset.
In [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining),instruction is to run the following command:

```
cd ~
curl -O http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz
tar xzf flower_photos.tgz
```

Also to download Inception-v3 model,the following code is given:

```
wget http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_dec_2015.zip
unzip tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/inception_dec_2015.zip
```

However, both commands give me syntax error...
May I know how to properly run the command in python?

I can also manually download the flower dataset (tgz file) and inception model (pb file) from the link, but I don't know how to load dataset and inception model to pycharm...

Any ideas?

Comment: those are not python commands, but intended for the command line.

Comment: 'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command： Seems it's still not working for cmd..

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows

Comment: Then you don't have wget, curl, or tar installed by default. This is not a python/tensorflow, etc (your tags) problem.